Flutter app_tracking_transparency
Flutter 3.22.0
Dart 3.4.0
pod 1.15.2
app_tracking_transparency: ^2.0.5
When building with xcode, "
Showing Recent Issues
/StudioProjects/**/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:12:9: Module 'app_tracking_transparency' not found
” error occurs.
cd ios
rm -rf Podfile.lock Pods
pod install --repo-update
cd ..
flutter clean
flutter pub get
I reinstalled it again, but app_tracking_transparency.framework is missing in the ios/.symlinks/plugins/app_tracking_transparency/ios directory and I still get the same error.

This solution worked for me:

Navigate to <PROJECT_NAME>.xcproject / <PROJECT_NAME>.xcworkspace -> General -> Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content and add AppTrackingTransparency.framework
Add NSUserTrackingUsageDescription in Info.plist
flutter pub get
Restart XCode

P.S. I found 1 and 2 steps here

Check that you are opening Runner.xcworkspace instead of Runner.xcodeproj in Xcode. I had that error that I mistakenly opened the wrong file in Xcode.
